# Better way to save image in custom field

Tags: custom-field, images

When I store image as custom field value, I currently use a plugin, Types Toolset. Basically it saves the full path of image after uploading the image, and it calls the value and put it as img tag's src value. So I can't get the benefit of srcset or somewhat.

There's also pros, it is easy to use and not spending time to run Wp Query.

Here is my questions. What do you think about save only id of images instead of full path? In addition, is there any way to set srcset from full path of image?

Thanks

Comment: You can store the image attachment id in your custom fields that will be fine